# Hibernate envers causes database lock

Tags: spring, hibernate, sql-server-2008, hibernate-envers

I have created a very simple Spring application with simple Java model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_CONTACT")
@Audited
public class TestContact {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5458933169009292797L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false, length = 128)
    @Length(max = 128)
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false, length = 128)
    @Length(max = 128)
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Like you can see I used Envers to track changes on my model. I also created MS SQL server scripts to load model:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TEST_CONTACT]     ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_CONTACT](
    [ID] [numeric](19, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FIRST_NAME] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [LAST_NAME] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

/****** Object:  Table [history].[TEST_CONTACT_AUD] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [history].[TEST_CONTACT_AUD](
    [ID] [numeric](19, 0) NOT NULL,
    [AUDIT_REVISION] [numeric](19, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ACTION_TYPE] [smallint] NULL,
    [FIRST_NAME] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [LAST_NAME] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [AUDIT_REVISION] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [history].[TEST_CONTACT_AUD]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CONTACT_AUD_REVINFO2] FOREIGN KEY([AUDIT_REVISION])
REFERENCES [history].[REVINFO] ([REV])
GO
ALTER TABLE [history].[TEST_CONTACT_AUD] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CONTACT_AUD_REVINFO2]
GO
```

I implemented simple repository to just create records in db:

```
@Repository
public class TestContactReposioryImpl implements TestContactReposiory {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void create(TestContact testContact) {
        em.persist(testContact);
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

I discovered that during around 20 requests to create TestContact model my database somehow is blocked (MS SQL server doesn't show any logs), application is also locked. I am getting only information that around 8 records tried to be inserted (seems that audit was not inserted):

```
DEBUG 2016-12-11 19:16:28,483 org.hibernate.SQL - insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
DEBUG 2016-12-11 19:16:32,003 org.hibernate.SQL - insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
DEBUG 2016-12-11 19:16:32,557 org.hibernate.SQL - insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
DEBUG 2016-12-11 19:16:33,101 org.hibernate.SQL - insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
DEBUG 2016-12-11 19:16:33,477 org.hibernate.SQL - insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
DEBUG 2016-12-11 19:16:33,741 org.hibernate.SQL - insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
DEBUG 2016-12-11 19:16:33,974 org.hibernate.SQL - insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
DEBUG 2016-12-11 19:16:34,193 org.hibernate.SQL - insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into TEST_CONTACT (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) values (?, ?)
```

This is what I discovered:
- if I perform around 5 requests everything is working fine,
- if I comment `@Audited` annotation so it means I won't use Hibernate envers tracking, everything is working fine, I could even run 50 requests to create TestContact records

---

UPDATE:

I noticed that it is somehow related to the Apache Commons DBCP and its default settings. If I change parameters:

- maxActive = 100
- maxIdle = 100
- maxOpenPreparedStatements = 100

then issue doesn't exist. Looks like I found out the solution, but I do not understand the root cause of issue.

---

UPDATE 2:

Attached service:

```
@Service
public class TestContactServiceImpl implements TestContactService {

    @Autowired
    private TestContactRepository testContactRepository;


    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PERM_CREATE_TEST_CONTACT')")
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void create(TestContact testContact) {
        testContactRepository.create(testContact);
    }
}
```

Attached controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/secure/sh/testcontact")
public class TestContactController {

    @Autowired
    private TestContactService testContactService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> create(@RequestBody @Valid TestContact testContact) throws IOException {
        testContactService.create(testContact);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Do you have any clues what could be wrong? It seems for me like Hibernate Envers issue, but I do not see the root cause of this issue. Please, let me know if you ever meet with this kind of issue.

Comment: Have you tried checking through SQL Server Studio whether there are any database table locks and if so, what SQL is associated with the lock?

Comment: Yes, but there's no running locks

Comment: Can you post your service / controller where transaction management is handled?  My guess is additional connections are being requested and your connection pool is exhausted; though I would expect an exception unless by default DBCP waits until one is free.

Comment: Ok, I updated topic and added service and controller. Please, take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Envers typically reuses the same database connection associated with the user's `EntityManager` or `Session` in order to flush the audit work queue during the transaction commit callback.

However, there are times where Hibernate Envers may need to acquire an additional `Session`, thus an additional database connection, in order to perform specific actions to avoid tainting the original user's `Session` state.

**Get Target Entity from Hibernate Proxy**

This scenario happens only when a `PersistentCollection` is modified that contains entity proxies.  This forces Envers to introduce a `CollectionChangeWorkUnit` and requires that a temporary session be opened in order to acquire the identifier of the proxied entity.

Since your code doesn't reflect any collections being modified, this is likely not the problem.

**Committing Audit Work Queue**

The audit work queue is a collection of `AuditWorkUnit`s that describe what operations the user has done to various managed persistent types and drive what Hibernate Envers must do to synchronize the audit tables with the user's schema.

The work queue participates as a callback to the transaction, which fires right before it completes.  This typically allows Hibernate Envers to push all the `AuditWorkUnit` changes to the audit tables as part of the same user transaction that modified the entities, allowing the process to be atomic.

There are situations that can influence this, forcing Hibernate Envers to push the `AuditWorkUnit` changes in a different connection.

1. The user session's flush mode is set to `COMMIT`.
2. The user session has been closed.

In these cases, Hibernate Envers will open a **new** `Session` which will be released after the transaction completes, starts a transaction, flushes the `AuditWorkUnit`s and then closes the temporary session.  This does mean a new database connection will be acquired for this newly opened session.

**Conclusion**

Given that there are situations where additional connections are necessary to perform various tasks without tainting the user session, its important that your connection pool be sized appropriately.  When you modified your connection pool settings, this is why the problem disappeared.

Hope that helps.